# How to render button in DataRow using ASP.NET Webforms?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a button every row using DataRow. I can't understand if is possible to render a button on a datarow?

```
 for (int day = 0; day < days.Count; day++)
                        {
                            // dataRow[string.Format("Day{0}", day + 1)] = days[day].Price;

                            // TODO: Store to hidden field.

                            var button = new Button();

                            button.ID = string.Format("{0}", day);
                            button.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block; padding:4px; width:100%; height:100%;");

                            dataRow[day + 1] = GridViewPricing.Controls.Add(button);
                        }
```

Alternetive:

I create a string html tags but it just render as string on the gridview.

Comment: If you want to add buttons to Rows of GridView, use TemplateField of GridView...

Comment: You don't add controls directly to `GridView` in asp. You need to reach at the `Cell` level and then use `AddControl`.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice to do this using web forms as the following :

Disable auto generate columns of grid using `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` then define the columns manually to fit your requirements like the example below.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="LabelName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then in code behind you can indicate what is the primary key of clicked column , something like this :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;

    if (gvr.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string Namme = (gvr.FindControl("LabelName") as Label).Text;
        //Write Query here to Delete Data
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewName" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="RowCommandEvent">
<Columns>
.
.
rest of the columns
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ColumnHeader">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="ButtonName" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>'>Edit</asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

you can add a button from a design side, using this you can get the button in every row of the grid.